# UrlFetchApp.fetch() gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON about 1/5 of the time Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I have been using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` for years with no issues

But recently, I randomly get this error message about once every five times I refreshed.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

I have spent hours researching how to fix this but found nothing that works.

Any insight is appreciated.

```
function fetch() {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sum-app.net/projects/151546202312131392/download_data/kumu_json").getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(source);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an online html validator? - [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your server is sending Html and not json. This might happen due to various reasons, like rate limiting(in which case, you can try [exponential backoff algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62859736)) or internal server errors.

```
function fetch() {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sum-app.net/projects/151546202312131392/download_data/kumu_json"),
    source = res.getContentText(),
    code = res.getResponseCode();
  if(code === 200){
     const data = JSON.parse(source);
     return data;
  } else {
     console.error({code})
     console.error(res.getContentText())
     throw new Error("Oops! Something went wrong!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using your `exponential backoff algorithm)` from the posted link. Thank you